# FileZilla as local files manager - comparing files and directories on local disks

Tags: file-management, comparison, filezilla, file-comparison

Is there a way to open local directory instead of server directory?

Do you know if there is some plugin to make it avaible?

I would like to use FileZilla as local file manager just to compare directories as FileZilla does it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such option in FileZilla. Check the source code to e.g. `CContextControl`. It's just not in there (`RemoteListView` etc. are clearly only remote by design).

---

You could run an FTP server on your local machine and open a connection to `localhost`.

If you're on OS X, open *System Preferences » Sharing*, then check *Remote Login*. This will also allow SFTP access.

If you're on Windows, you could try running FileZilla Server.